# Django ORM filter by lowercase only

Tags: python, django, django-orm

How do I use Django ORM to filter objects that only show the lowercase only?
For example in my case, I want to update all emails that has "non-lowercase" objects to "lowercase".

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

User.objects.exclude(email__islower=True).update(email=Lower("email"))
                             /|\
                              |
```

Comment: i think the best solution will be to convert the email in lowercase while you are saving it in the database.

Comment: Does just updating all rows without the filter perform any worse than using your regex? `User.objects.all().update(email=Lower("email"))`

Comment: @IainShelvington I know it, but I don't want to use it, because when we have 1 million of Users, then it will take a time. So, that's why I need to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I'm using `__regex` expression to solve this,

```
User.objects.exclude(email__regex="^[a-z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$").update(email=Lower("email"))
```

with this email patterns: https://www.abstractapi.com/tools/email-regex-guide

But, hopefully there would have any better solutions.